# What to do about "File 'Array' presents a security risk and should be deleted." on 4.7?

Tags: upgrade, 4.7

After some brief difficulty upgrading from Civi 4.6.x to 4.7.0, we managed to get it done, with one small hiccup.  Post-installation, we got a notification saying:

```
File 'Array' presents a security risk and should be deleted.
```

I looked in our CiviCRM directory, and found 2 files called "Array.php" I tried temporarily relocating both of those files, but no luck; the error still displayed.  Any leads as to how to resolve this issue would help--it makes me uncomfortable to have the system status as "Critical."

Thanks!

Comment: Me too. Upgrade ran through flawlessly, but the System status page shows the error described here.

Joomla 3.4.8, CiviCRM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CiviCRM is *not* warning you about a file named `Array.php`, the confusing error message is because it's rendering a PHP array to a text string.

I've opened an issue in JIRA about this and submitted a suggested quick fix:

[CRM-17909: File 'Array' presents a security risk and should be deleted.](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17909)

It looks like the fix is as simple as adding `[0]` as shown [in this Github commit](https://github.com/xurizaemon/civicrm-core/commit/50208d1e0d3bea9c0f45ff52bbfe0a31ad81ed2c).

If you can test the fix from that issue on your site, and confirm that the error message shows a more helpful result when you've done so, that will help us get the fix into the next 4.7.x release.

Comment: The files reported after the fix in Joomla are `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/packages/dompdf/dompdf.php` and `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/packages/html2text/class.html2text.inc`. Removing them cleared the warnings.